# Twilio: Trace replied SMS

Tags: c#, twilio

i'm new to twilio. I have a situation is like i have two application sharing a short-code number while sending messages. When a user receive a SMS from application(A) and replied the SMS. How i can know the message replied by the user is mean for the application(A) not application(B)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The best way to do this is to use different numbers for each application. Then you know which application the user is sending the message to. You could use long codes if more than one short code is too expensive.

The only other way to know that would be to have keywords for application A and B and insisting users include that keyword.

For example, you could have applications about sports. If the user wanted to find out about football, they'd send the message "FOOTBALL" plus whatever else you want from them. But if they wanted to find out about tennis, they'd message "TENNIS" plus whatever.

Then your application would need to search the [body of the SMS message](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request) for the keyword, then deal with the messages once they were sorted.

Other than that, there's no way to know as there is no message threading in SMS.

Comment: Hi @philnash, thanks for your reply! Let me ask another question, what if a user receive a SMS from SubAcount(A) and replied the SMS. Is it the same situation as the question above or is it possible to track the responded message is mean to the SubAcount(A)?

Comment: There is nothing within SMS that defines what message you are replying to. If you take a look at your own phone and SMS app, you will see there is no way to reply to a specific message, just a linear timeline of messages. That's all you have to work with I'm afraid.

Comment: Okay, got it. Thank you berry much evangelist :)

Comment: No problem! Hope you find a solution for your application.